# Rxjs: How to filter data based on inner value of a list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, angular, rxjs

I retrieve data by using the following method:

```
this.employeeService
    .getList()
    .subscribe((list: any) => {
        this.list = list;
});
```

But there are 2 property in the `list`, one of them is `data`, the other is `count`. So, I need to apply filter according to `list.data.isManager` property without destructing list (I need to keep `data` and  `count` properties). So, I need something like that:

```
this.employeeService
    .getList()
    .subscribe((list: any) => {
        this.list = list.filter(x => x.data.isManager === true);
});
```

But as the list is not array, it throws error. I need to apply filter according to `list.data.isManager`. So, how can I fix this problem? Should I use `map` operator?

Here is sample data of the list variable:

***list:***

```
count: 5
data: Array(5)
0: EmployeeListDto {isManager: true, id: 1, name: "John"}
1: EmployeeListDto {isManager: true, id: 2, name: "Mark"}
2: EmployeeListDto {isManager: true, id: 3, name: "Alice"}
3: EmployeeListDto {isManager: true, id: 4, name: "Mary"}
4: EmployeeListDto {isManager: true, id: 5, name: "Federic"}
```

Comment: If it's not an array you can't call `map()` on it either. Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: what''s the expected value of this.list if isManager is true and if isanager is false?

Comment: @pilchard I added sample data for list. Thanks.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon I just want to retrieve the items for which `isManager === true`.  But while comparing items, I want to keep the list with its  `count` and `data` properties and values.

Comment: arguably the `count` will no longer be accurate once you filter the `data`.

Comment: @Fredrick fine, i added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isManager` isn't a property of data but a property of an item of the *data* array.

So you need to place your filter on your *data property* (and keep the count property):

```
const filteredList = list.data.filter(item => item.isManager);
this.list = {
  count: filteredList.length,
  data: filteredList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Merely:

```
this.list ={ 
  data: list.data.filter(x => x.isManager),
  count: // ...
};
```

The value of *count* could be

1. `list.count` if you want the original count
2. `list.data.filter(x => x.isManager).length` if you want the after-filtering count. In this case, it is cleaner to do :

```
    this.list ={ 
          data: list.data.filter(x => x.isManager),
        };
    
     this.list['count'] = this.list.data.length;
```

** you do not need to `x.isManager === true`, javascript manage it internally.

Answer (score 1):

data inside the list is a array so you can use `filter`

```
 this.list = list.data.filter(x => x.isManager === true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process your data is reactive way, you can process your filtering like

```
this.employeeService
.getList()
.pipe(
  concatMap(arr => from(arr)),
  filter((ele: any) => ele.isManager)
 )
.subscribe((list: any) => {
    this.list = list;
});
```